# Sort numeric data with HTML in DataTables

Tags: jquery, datatables

I am using DataTables plugin version 1.10.13. In my table, column at index `5` contains a Bootstrap progress bar, and the resulting HTML looks somewhat like this:

```
<td>
    <div class="progress"
           style="margin-bottom:0px;"
           title="10% Complete"
             data-placement="top"
             data-toggle="popover"
             data-trigger="hover"
             data-html="true"
             data-content="
                Some data here...
             "
    >
      <div class="progress-bar " role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="10"
           aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 10%;">
        <span class="sr-only">10</span>
      </div>
    </div>
</td>
```

Now, without any options, DataTables sorts this columns alphabetically, so records with the progress bar of 90 are at the very top, while the one with 100, 10, and finally 0 are at the bottom. The problem is that 100 is supposed to be at the very top.

I tried `html-num`, `html-num-fmt`, `num`, and a handful of others, but they either don't work or sort alphabetically. Basically, the goal here is to sort numerically, and not alphabetically. I also tried displaying the value (e.g. 10 or 100) inside the `<td>` itself, but it didn't change anything. At this point, I am not even sure how DataTables reads the HTML markup. Does it look at the `<span>` with the class of `sr-only`?

Can someone suggest a solution?

#### EDIT

@Gyrocode.com created a great jsfiddle. I added more records to show the problem: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/k4aauf0n/1/)

Comment: Works even without specifying the type, see http://jsfiddle.net/k4aauf0n/

Comment: @Gyrocode.com It sort alphabetically. So, if you have 0, 10, 20, 50, 90, 100 it would sort them in descending order as 90, 50, 20, 100, 10, 0. I am trying to get 100, 90, 50, 20, 10, 0. Try [jsfiddle.net/k4aauf0n/1/](http://jsfiddle.net/k4aauf0n/1/) and click on `Progress` `<th>`. I do appreciate the fiddle though, thanks!

Comment: Your fiddle has a typo, it works for me without any sorting plugins, see http://jsfiddle.net/k4aauf0n/2/. However there is also [`num-html`](https://datatables.net/plug-ins/sorting/num-html) but again it works for me without plugins.

Comment: Huh, a typo? Can't see any

Comment: One of the progress bars in your example had value `90` but width of `10%` which looked as result of a wrong sort operation. Here is how column appear for me in http://jsfiddle.net/k4aauf0n/2/, it's sorted correctly from 10,30,90,90 to 100, see https://i.stack.imgur.com/9WsLb.png

Comment: @Gyrocode.com Thank you for your help! I made another fiddle, this time with progress bar only. I checked all values and they seem to be matching there. However, the sorting is completely messed up and I can't see why... Any ideas why it doesn't work? [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/k4aauf0n/7/)

Comment: I agree, its type detection doesn't seem consistent, not sure what's going on. I suggest forcing sorting with a sorting plugin such as `num-html`, see my answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`num-html`](https://datatables.net/plug-ins/sorting/num-html) sorting plugin.

```js
$.extend($.fn.dataTableExt.oSort, {
    "num-html-pre": function ( a ) {
        var x = String(a).replace( /<[\s\S]*?>/g, "" );
        return parseFloat( x );
    },

    "num-html-asc": function ( a, b ) {
        return ((a < b) ? -1 : ((a > b) ? 1 : 0));
    },

    "num-html-desc": function ( a, b ) {
        return ((a < b) ? 1 : ((a > b) ? -1 : 0));
    }
} );

$(document).ready(function() {
    var table = $('#example').DataTable({
       columnDefs: [
          { targets: 0, type: 'num-html' }
       ]
    });
} );
```

See [updated jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/k4aauf0n/6/) for code and demonstration.

Comment: Any reason why it seemed to worked in your example before, but not in mine now?

Comment: @Alex, not sure yet. It has type detection mechanism built-in but using `num-html` forces use of specific sorting method.

Comment: Thank you once again, you've put a fair bit of work into this. I've tried it on my page with 100+ records, and even with v. 1.10.9 (I previously tried v. 1.10.13, in which `num-html` is now deprecated) the progress bars are randomly sorted, and I can't see any logical patterns whatsoever. I guess at this point, I'll take a step further and report this on their github page and in their forums. Thanks again for your input!

Comment: @Alex, you must be doing something wrong as it works for me even with 1.10.13, see http://jsfiddle.net/k4aauf0n/8/

Comment: After trial and error, I finally found out that the Bootstrap popover was messing up sorting. Once removed, sorting went back to normal, even without any options for DataTables. I guess it modified innerHtml or sth like that. Anyways, thanks